# Append <figure> tag at the starting and ending of <img> tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, string

I want to append figure tag at the starting and ending of `image` tag.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
<?php
    $v['content_en'] = '<p><br /><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png"/><br /><br /><br />The Italian-born gallerist took to the art world like some take to religion. He can be accountable for launching the careers of Rauschenberg, Twombly, Lichtenstein, Oldenburg, Stella, Judd, Flavin, Serra, and ensuring that their work was bought by the world&rsquo;s most prestigious museums.<br /> He prefered to sell to informed and engaged collectors and in all cases to philanthropists rather than speculators.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.wsj.com/articles/the-art-of-larry-gagosians-empire-1461677075" target="_blank">billion dollar annual revenue&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;are the perfect example.<br /><br />With not much space left for philosophy and introspection, today artists have to be most of all &nbsp;good communicators to get an exhibition&hellip;</p><p><br />';

    //$tmp=  preg_replace('#<img(.*)/>(.+)#i', '<figure><img$1/></figure>', $v['content_en'], -1);
    $v['content_en'] = preg_replace('#<img(.*)/>(.+)#i', '<figure><img$1>$2</figure>', $v['content_en'], -1);
    //$returnValue = preg_replace('#<img(.*)>(.+)</img>#i', '<figure><img$1>$2</img></figure>', $v['content_en'], -1);
    print_r($v['content_en']);
?>
```

`$v['content_en']` is my string that I am fetching from database for each record.
I am not getting expected result what happens is that `</figure>` get appended at the end of my content but it should be ended after `<imp>` tag get ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, if I understood you correctly:

```
$v['content_en'] = '<p><br /><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png"/><br /><br /><br />The Italian-born gallerist took to the art world like some take to religion. He can be accountable for launching the careers of Rauschenberg, Twombly, Lichtenstein, Oldenburg, Stella, Judd, Flavin, Serra, and ensuring that their work was bought by the world&rsquo;s most prestigious museums.<br /><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png"/> He prefered to sell to informed and engaged collectors and in all cases to philanthropists rather than speculators.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.wsj.com/articles/the-art-of-larry-gagosians-empire-1461677075" target="_blank">billion dollar annual revenue&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;are the perfect example.<br /><br />With not much space left for philosophy and introspection, today artists have to be most of all &nbsp;good communicators to get an exhibition&hellip;</p><p><br /><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png"/>';
$returnValue = preg_replace('#<img(.*)\s?/>#iU', '<figure><img$1 $2></figure>', $v['content_en'], -1);
echo $returnValue;
```

Result will be:

```
<p><br /><figure><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png" ></figure><br /><br /><br />The Italian-born gallerist took to the art world like some take to religion. He can be accountable for launching the careers of Rauschenberg, Twombly, Lichtenstein, Oldenburg, Stella, Judd, Flavin, Serra, and ensuring that their work was bought by the world&rsquo;s most prestigious museums.<br /><figure><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png" ></figure> He prefered to sell to informed and engaged collectors and in all cases to philanthropists rather than speculators.<br /><br /><a href="http://www.wsj.com/articles/the-art-of-larry-gagosians-empire-1461677075" target="_blank">billion dollar annual revenue&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;are the perfect example.<br /><br />With not much space left for philosophy and introspection, today artists have to be most of all &nbsp;good communicators to get an exhibition&hellip;</p><p><br /><figure><img alt="" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/9dc27741114bd854f29fc65dc3321958/tumblr_o9zo20vMVP1uom2zvo1_1280.png" ></figure>
```

Comment: <image /> will be ended by  /> not using </img> so in that case what will be regexp for that? @hardy rust

Comment: your code is working for me when i changed regexp but now the problem is that </figure> is appended after all my html content means at the end of string but i want it after </img> closes.

Comment: Could you please give a content example and the result you wish to have?

Comment: i have updated my question with an example in which i am getting figure tag at the end of html content @hardy rust

Comment: i got the answer! the regexp will be  
$v['content_en'] = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>(?:<\/img>)?)/i', '<figure>$1<figure />', $v['content_en']);

your answer required slight change to work for me.and i did it.
and now it's working as i expected
thanks for your answer @hardy rusty

Answer (score 0):

```
$v['content_en'] = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>(?:<\/img>)?)/i', '<figure>$1<figure />', $v['content_en']);
```